# How to get IP Address using Qt Framework

Tags: qt, ip

I want to get the IP Address and the country in which it belongs using Qt please help me with examples. thank you for your time.
I tried this code

```
foreach (const QHostAddress &address, QNetworkInterface::allAddresses()) {
    if (address.protocol() == QAbstractSocket::IPv6Protocol && address != QHostAddress(QHostAddress::LocalHost)) {
         qDebug() << address.toString();
    }
}
```

but it did not work, i want to get the IP like the one witch gives the website http://whatismyipaddress.com/fr/mon-ip it gives the IP Address and the country in witch it belogns.
 Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: "It did not work" is not a technical description of a problem. What's the expected behavior? What happens when you run the code?

Comment: i'm sorry i'm new here i want to get IP Address of the computer in witch my application run and the country in witch this IP Address belongs. please help me i need your help

Comment: What didn't work? Did you get an error (please write the error code) or did you just get an wrong IP adress? Also note: There is an prefix in IP6 adress, which may change over time. (Like it was in IP4 adresses). Also note: For IP4 adresses there are private (local network) and internet adresses. - I think you expect the internet IP4 adress? (In contrast to the local IP4 adress of your computer). - Then you should use QAbstractSocket::**IPv4Protocol**